# How to fit 3 Panels in a Frame with wxPython

Tags: wxpython

My problem is that i have three panels that i want to give the vertical dimensions and for horizontal to take the size of the frame

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's not very clear what you're asking. Posting the relevant code could help. : )

Comment: A sketch of what you're talking about would help too

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example taken from the wx demo.

```
box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
box.Add(SampleWindow(win, "one"), 0, wx.EXPAND)
box.Add(SampleWindow(win, "two"), 0, wx.EXPAND)
box.Add(SampleWindow(win, "three"), 0, wx.EXPAND)
box.Add(SampleWindow(win, "four"), 0, wx.EXPAND)
```

And the result looks like:

[image]

If this isn't what you're looking for, there's probably something else in the demo that would work.  Get the demo from [here](http://www.wxpython.org/download.php), and the sizer examples are under `Window Layout | Sizers`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the panels to have different sizes you should use maybe a FlexGridSizer. Something like:

```
sizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(4, 1, 0, 0)
sizer.AddGrowableRow(3)
first_panel = wx.Panel(self)
second_panel = wx.Panel(self)
third_panel = wx.Panel(self)
first_panel.SetPrefferedSize((-1, custom_height1))
second_panel.SetPrefferedSize((-1, custom_height2))
third_panel.SetPrefferedSize((-1, custom_height3))
sizer.Add(first_panel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
sizer.Add(second_panel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
sizer.Add(third_panel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
sizer.Add((-1, -1))
```

If sizes are not kept you can try replacing SetPrefferedSize with SetMinSize altought I don't really recommend it.